# How to get the JSON array from server to Jquery mobile application

Tags: jquery, rest, jquery-mobile, getjson

I have a REST based webservice which returns json array like
`[{"name":"abc","age":"24","gender":"female"}]`. I used this webservice from my Jquery Mobile application like

```
$.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/webservice/name", { name: +$("name") }, function(resultList){
    alert("JSON Data: " + resultList.age);
  });
```

But I am getting "undefined" in my alert box. How to return the JSON Array from webservice. What could be the issue here?

Comment: `resultList` is an array of JSON objects, it will / can contain more than one JSON object. So attempting `resultList.age` is never going to work--you need to access a specific index within `resultList` before grabbing its `age` attribute. See the answer from Aziz for more.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this and see if it works:

```
$.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/webservice/name", { name: +$("name") }, function(resultList){
     $.each(resultList, function(key, val) {
          alert("JSON Data: key" + key + " value: " + value);
     });
});
```